# Sketch a graph of $f(x)=|x^2-1|-|x^2-4|$

Tags: absolute-value

Sketch a graph of $f(x)=|x^2-1|-|x^2-4|$

I thought in order to graph this function, I would try to rewrite $f$ as a piece-wise defined function. The zeros of the absolute values are at $x= \pm 1$ and $x= \pm 2$.

If $x \leq -2$ then $f(x)=x^2-1-x^2+4=3$

If $ -2<x<-1$ then $f(x)=x^2-1+x^2-4=2x^2-5$

If $ -1 \leq x \leq 1$ then $f(x)=1-x^2+x^2-4=-3$

If $ 1<x<2$ then $f(x)=x^2-1+x^2-4=2x^2-5$

if $ x \geq 2$ then $f(x)=x^2-1-x^2+4=3$

My problem is that equation $2$ and $4$ didn't match up when I went to graph it with a calculator. Was this the correct approach or would there be a better way for this particular function.

Comment: i don't see any problem. Your solution is correct.

Comment: The $2x^2-5$ pieces didn't match up when I graphed it online I got more of a linear equation for those pieces

Comment: @HighSchool15 I just plotted the given function on desmos. Your solution seems to be correct.

Comment: @HighSchool15 see here ::http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+%7Cx%5E2-1%7C-%7Cx%5E2-4%7C+and+2x%5E2-5::, they clearly match

Comment: Oops I mistyped first time thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is absolutely correct. But there is an easier way to solve your problem too. In particular, set $y = x^2$ to get
$$g(y)=|y-1|-|y-4|.$$
Now consider three intervals as follows.

- For $0 \le y \le 1$ (equivalently, $-1 \le x \le 1$), $$g(y)=1-y-(4-y)=-3\implies f(x)=-3.$$
- For $1 < y < 4$ (equivalently, $1<|x|<2$ or $x \in (-2,-1)\cup(1,2)$), $$g(y)=y-1-(4-y)=2y-5 \implies f(x)=2x^2-5.$$
- For $y \ge 4$ (equivalently, $|x| \ge2$ or $x \in (-\infty,-2] \cup [2, \infty)$), $$g(y)=y-1-(y-4)=3 \implies f(x)=3.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is called graph paper. You can plot points on it and then join them up.  As far as the vertical placement relative to the smaller squares, between $1$ and $2,$ we have
$$ 2 \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^2 - 5 = - \frac{1}{2},  $$
$$ 2 \left(1 + \frac{k}{4} \right)^2 - 5 = k-3 + \frac{k^2}{8}, \; \; \; \;  k = 1,3.  $$
$$ 2 \left(1 + \frac{k}{8} \right)^2 - 5 = -3 + \frac{k}{2} + \frac{k^2}{32}, \; \; \; \;  k = 1,3,5,7.  $$

$1/8$ is half a small square, $1/32$ is an eighth of a small square.

[image]

https://www.printablepaper.net/